# What magic makes object.getClass() in Java return a typed Class instance?

Tags: java, generics

In Java, `Object.getClass` has a type signature of `public final Class<?> getClass()`, but the JavaDoc comment mentions that it will really be "`Class<? extends |X|>` where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is called".

This is indeed the case and enforced by the compiler, supported by the IDE:s etc, but what magic make this tick? Does the compiler treat this method in a special way? Does it actually generate an override of `getClass()` for each type?

I understand that this is solely a compile time construct, at runtime it will not make any difference what the generic type parameter of Class is/was.

Comment: In short: As far as I know, methods with generic return types get their actual parameter from the context it is called. So e.g. the type of the variable the result is assigned to. This behaviour would be with all methods, `getClass()` is no special case there. But I think somebody with a more established knowledge should better answer this ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the compiler treats the method specially.  For example, see calls to `createGetClassMethod()` in Eclipse's compiler in the [Scope](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/compiler/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/Scope.java#n2435) class.  (There are a few other calls to this method in the same class.)

Comment: Note that this method is specifically called out in the JLS, along with the typing requirements: [JLS 4.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)

Comment: Yes, OP noted that the javadoc does mention this, though the JLS is the authority as you point out.  It's interesting to note that javadoc primarily documents high-level or JVM-level semantics, but occasionally Java-semantics are added for clarity.

Comment: Yup, agreed. The only reason I thought it was worth noting is that one could reasonably ask, "why should a compiler have to special-case this method just cause the javadocs say it's different? What makes `java.lang.Class#getMethod` more special than `com.myname.Foo#Bar`? _I_ don't get to special-case a return value!" And the answer is that it's special because the JLS specifically designates it as so. Maybe a pedantic point, but to me it's significant. :)